# traversing a multiarray with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi guys I have this array :

```
[[2,3,0],[0,4,5]]
```

and i want traverse this array like:

```
[[2,0],
 [3,4],
 [0,5]]
```

Any recommendations please? I am working with javascript

Comment: Will there be only 2 nested array elements?

Comment: could be more , i want something that is generic which works with loops if possible

Comment: "Transposing a 2D-array" answers work in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = [
  [2, 3, 0],
  [0, 4, 5],
];

const result = arr[0].map((val, i) => {
  return Array(arr.length)
    .fill("")
    .map((_, index) => arr[index][i]);
});

console.log(result);
```